# can't find package vtk while executing "package require vtk"

Tags: cmake, tcl, data-visualization, vtk

The way I run and execute my tcl script is as following:

```
% ~  pwd
/Users/username/VTK/Examples/Tutorial/Step1/Tcl
% ~  export TCLLIBPATH=/Users/username/VTKBIN/Wrapping/Tcl
% ~  tclsh Cone.tcl
can't find package vtk
    while executing
"package require vtk"
    (file "Cone.tcl" line 12)
```

I have run this script before and it has worked, but now it is not.

(This is Mac OSX 10.7 running VTK 6.0)

Comment: What changed between the last time you ran it and now?

Comment: I was exporting the wrong path.